# Como validar un Trigger con una Funcion ? - Oracle

Tags: oracle

Aun estoy incursando el mundo de Oracle y me encontré con una Situación. Apreciaría hasta la mas mínima sugerencia
o ayuda :).

Ahora, tengo una Tabla "SENSOR" con un campo "QUERYS" este campo tiene registros con unas consultas que simplemente devolverán valores numéricos. 
Para hacer posible esto construí una Función:
Lo único que hace mi Función es cargar estas Consultas en mi Tabla Sensor y claro devolverme sus respectivos valores.

Un ejemplo seria el Siguiente:

```
SELECT FN_INDICADOR(IDSENSOR) FROM SENSOR;
```

Esto me devolverá los valores ya cargados.

Tengo un Trigger que lo único que básicamente hase es registrar la Fecha Actual en mi campo "Actualización" luego de Modificado un registro de cualquier campo en mi tabla SENSOR.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t1
 BEFORE UPDATE ON SENSOR REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD 
 FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE 
  v_fecha DATE;
 BEGIN
   v_fecha :=SYSDATE;
   SELECT SYSDATE INTO v_fecha FROM DUAL;
   :NEW.ACTUALIZACION :=v_fecha;
 END;
```

Lo que tenia pensando hacer es invocar mi Función desde este Trigger para que cumpla la siguiente Validación:

Cada vez que los valores que devuelva mi función varíen o se modifiquen se registre en mi campo "ACTUALIZACIÓN" la Fecha en que fue alterado ese valor.
Si algunos se logran preguntar como estos valores van a variar o van a cambiar es porque esta tabla se encuentra en producción por lo que sus valores se encontraran en constante cambio.

Si hay otra solución seria genial :D, espero que me haya dejado entender.

Comment: Podes agregar ejemplos de datos y las tablas, sigo sin entender que tiene que hacer la funcion, porque el trigger ya sabe la fecha de la actualizacion (es sysdate), entonces que fecha queres poner donde?

Comment: La función lo único que hace es Cargar unas Consultas que están establecías en mi Campo "QUERYS" de mi tabla sensor y convertirlas en valores, en la pregunta anterior mostré el código de la Fucion :) o si deseas lo vuelvo a colocar.

Comment: La funcion que pusiste en la otra pregunta (recorda poner un enlace en esta pregunta, si es necesario, si no copia la funcion aca), solo devolvia un valor. No cargaba nada en ningun lado. habras copiado la funcion equivocada?

Comment: Exacto solo devuelve un valor.

Comment: La función es la misma solo que use la palabra equivocada con cargar en ves de devolver D:. y Bueno lograste Entender mi Funcion.

Comment: y que es lo que queres hacer con ese valor?

Comment: Mira, ese valor que devuelve como lo dije arriba, si o si va a cambiar o variar, lo que quiero hacer es si cambia registrar la fecha en la que fue alterada, nada mas

Comment: y contra que lo vas a comparar?

Comment: Bueno, eso queria saber, aun no tengo claro que proceso hacer, por eso pesaba usar ese trigger pero nose si sea lo correcto D:

Comment: ahhh ahi esta el problema.. estas confundido.. tu trigger, tiene que estar en la tabla donde cambian los valores. y cada vez que ese valor cambia, en un campo (u otra tabla, o donde sea) registrar la fecha. Estas confundiendo todo el proceso :)

Comment: D: Entiendo, Bueno entonces esa seria la unica forma ?